# Show or Hide DIV from Code Behind

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have a DIV with an Image inside:

```
<div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none' runat="server">
      <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." style="padding: 20px;position:fixed;top:35%;left:50%;" />
```

I can show and hide the image in jquery like this:

```
$('#loadingmessage').show();
$('#loadingmessage').hide();
```

I want to do the same from code behind after I have clicked on a asp:RadioButton:

```
public void OnCheckedColumnMethodRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//hier I want to show the DIV and before the method is closed i want to hide it
```

I tried:

```
loadingmessage.Visible = true;
loadingmessage.Style["display"] = "block";
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `OnCheckedColumnMethodRequest` happens on the server, so the HTML is sent to the browser only after the method finishes, therefore the image will never be visible to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above are fine, I suggest changing it directly from JavaScript not manipulating it through the attributes but for each his own.

The future of DOM manipulation however lies in using binding frameworks  (E.g. Knockout) so that you control your page from a ViewModel making this kind of management obsolete.

```
        function toggelShowHide(elem) {
            if (elem.style.display == 'none') {
                elem.style.display = '';
            }
            else elem.style.display = 'none'
        }

        function toggelPicture()
        {           
            var picture = document.getElementById('myPicture');
            toggelShowHide(picture)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try hiding the element using CSS:

```
loadingmessage.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

Alternatively, to show:

```
loadingmessage.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the css attrribute [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) (default is *visible* else you can sey *hidden*)

E.g.: `loadingmessage.Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:visible");`